# Multiple view controllers with same tab controller

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

Am using tab controller in my application, i have 5 main tabs.
But each controller navigate to another controllers, i want the sub controllers to hav the same tabs and the tabbed tab will be the main controller it was navigated from ...

for example:

[image]

I want the controller in the red square to have the same main tabs and the tab in the middle is clicked when navigating to it ..

how to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to show the tab bar in all your controllers?

Comment: @V_rohit yes this is what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `UINavigationController` right after the `UITabBarController`.

For a quick Storyboard fix, select the first `UIViewController` after the `UITabBarController` and in Xcode menu do `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller`

[image]

Comment: @Lama glad to hear. One small note on this subject: The idea behind tabs, is for each tab to have it's own navigation stack.

Answer (score 2):

Connect all your First View Controllers that are attached to `TabBarController` with `UINavigationController` like this: [image]

The reason why we do this because we need to open other `ViewControllers` in our `TabBarController`. If we don't use `NavigationController` then it produce `nil` and doesn't show the `tabBar` on other `ViewControllers`.

Comment: thanks alot this is what i need! but sorry @thedp answered first .. thank you so much!

Comment: Not to worry... Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks.. you too :D!